# How can I redirect based on a selection of a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `TextBox1` and a Search button in my application with this following code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~\\searchpage.aspx?PatientNRIC=" + TextBox1.Text);
}
```

Which means, if the user type ONLY `IC NO:S1234567D`, then when click it will show the patient detailview.

So I now I'm doing almost the same thing but now I have a `TextBox2` and a `DropDownList1`. Inside `DropDownList1`, I have "Name", "IC No", "Test_Date".

So for an example, I type "S1234567D" in the textbox1, and I choose "IC No" in `DropDownList1` it should redirect me to a page of the S1234567D's patient detailview.

How could I do my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following might work for you:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(dropdownlist1.SelectedValue == "IC No")
    {
        // assuming this is the redirect to your patients details view
        // but you MUST use only forward slashes to make it work (!)
        Response.Redirect("~/searchpage.aspx?PatientNRIC=" + TextBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    name.Text = ddl1.DataTextField;
    ICNo.Text = ddl1.DataValueField;
    textBox1.Text = name.text+ICno.Text;
```

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if(textbox1 != null)
      {
          Response.Redirect("~/searchpage.aspx?PatientNRIC=" + TextBox1.Text);
      }
    }
}